# While creating a html file in java using file and file writer iam unable to use a title for the html file which contains special characters such as?

Tags: java, html, file, filewriter

```
String Template="<P>sooper</p>
String InputFolder="D:\\project"
String title="name"
FileWriter myWriter = null;
File htmlContent = new File(InputFolder + File.separator +  title+ ".html");
 myWriter = new FileWriter(htmlContent);
myWriter.write(Template);
myWriter.close();
```

This works fine

but when I replace the title with any string which contains special characters the html file is not being created[image: b]

I was expecting a html file would be created with the name name?.html

Comment: Please post the actual value of 'title' that you're using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is that you try to create a path (under Windows or Linux) with special characters which is not valid for path for your OS. You have to encode the path to the correct one with replasing non `ascii` symbols to its printable alternative.

```java
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    String template = "<p>sooper</p>";
    String parent = "d:/project";
    String title = "n   ame";

    File file = new File(parent, encode(title + ".html"));

    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        file.createNewFile();
    }

    try (FileWriter out = new FileWriter(file, true)) {
        out.write(template);
    }
}

private static String encode(String str) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    return URLEncoder.encode(str, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
}
```

Comment: The OS is *Windows*, the file names of which, afaik, are stored as UTF-16

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because there are spaces in your HTML file name. Can you try with Bharatiya_Janta_Party.html or Bharatiya-Janta-Party.html

Please do inform what results did you get.

Comment: That's not an *answer*. Also, all OSs that I know of have no problem having spaces in file names

Comment: Is file name & Application title the same thing in Java? Because it's not in HTML. I am asking this.

Comment: The space is not a problem it creates a file with space in name the problem is when we enter a special character like ?